# Installing ASP.Net Framework 3.5 on Server (From 2.0)

Tags: frameworks, installation, asp.net-3.5

I want to upgrade the Windows 2003 x86 server which is running ASP.NET 2.0, to support ASP.NET 3.5

Which file / files do I need?

Do I need to install 3.0 first, then 3.5, then 3.5 SP1, or will the full download of 3.5 SP1 (dotnetfx35.exe 3.5.30729.1, 231 MB) do everything?

Also, I believe I have to install the following at the end of the process:
NDP20SP2-KB958481-x86.exe,
NDP20SP2-KB958483-x86.exe,
NDP20SP2-KB958484-x86.exe

Will anything interfere with live applications currently running?

Thanks

Comment: Well, 3.5 SP1 was the correct install, however my 2.0 apps went offline during the install, going through different error types as the install progressed (server too busy, missing 2.0 web.config).
Once the install completed (I'm assuming the worker process restarted) everything was ok again.

Comment: The users experienced the following error: Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing 3.5 SP1 by itself will add everything you need.  I don't think live applications will be interrupted, but performance might be impacted while the installer is running.  Be sure to run Microsoft Update after as well for any post SP1 updates that might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install 3.5 SP1 :

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7&displaylang=en

I am not familiar with those specific KB hot fixes.  You can install it in parallel to .Net 2.0 and it will not affect those apps running under 2.0.